# setChecked in CheckBox returns java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I hope that you can help me with this. I have a XML with a checkBox control and I want change its to checked by code.

When Android Studio compiles, the code has an error in "cb.setChecked(true)". FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
cb.setChecked(true);
```

XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#ff8989"
          android:id="@+id/backColor"
          android:divider="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:longClickable="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="..."
        android:id="@+id/txt_tarea"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't really given us enough to go off of (your `onCreate()` and layout XML would help), but I think it should be fairly obvious that `cb` is null. `findViewById()` returns null when it can't find a view with the given ID, so I'm guessing that your layout is missing the `checkBox` element you are looking for.

Comment: share your layout xml file

Comment: The checkbox is into the XML with the correct id.

Comment: Possibly you haven't called `setContentView()` with that layout before calling `findViewById()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the id that you provide to findViewById. Is it present in your layout.xml. ALso have to inflated the view using that layout file before calling this. Please verify these points and I think your problem will be solved.

Comment: I can access to the TextView without problems. The checkbox is into the XML with the correct id.

Comment: What have you called in onCreate for your activity ? are you using the same layout file in setContentView ?

Comment: I have a ListView in which I inflate a XML that has a CheckBox with the TextView. I can access to TextView and setText without errors, but whit the checkBox control I have this error.

Comment: Your last comment made the problem really baffling, what was the bug ?

Comment: I used `CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);` and it was wrong. The correct code is `CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) item.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);` Thanks for help me.